# Only keep some data from mainframe in my SAS program

Tags: sas

Hope you can help.

**My problem is that i want to only keep some data from my mainframe server, because i have limited workspace in my SAS.**

My program code is:

How do i Keep Only LAENGDE and search on a specified number in LAENGDE?

```
   filename DG121'G41066.PUREX.HK000.WAB.HTB.DG121'; 

DATA WAB;


INFILE DG121 ;


INPUT
@   1   LAENGDE ?? IB2.
@   3   TOTANM  ?? IB2.
@   5   REXHTYP ?? IB2.
@   7   RMODTAFD ?? PD3.    
@   10  RANVDATO ?? PD5.
@   15  RKUNDENR ?? PD6.
@   21  RBRKODE ??  PD2.
@   23  RRAADGIV ?? ÅCHAR1.
@   24  RKUNDKAT ?? ÅCHAR3.
@   27  RMAXOPR ??  PD8.2
@   35  RLOBTIDO ?? PD2.
@   37  RPRODBET ?? ÅCHAR6.
@   43  RMEDIE ??   ÅCHAR5.
@   48  ROPSIG ??   ZD3.
@   51  RINDUDL ??  ÅCHAR1.
@   52  RKUNDGRP ?? ÅCHAR1.
@   53  L7HTYP ??   IB2.
@   55  L7TRGRP ??  IB2.
@   57  L7TRART ??  IB2.
@   59  L7TRTYP ??  IB2.
@   61  L7ANSAFD ?? IB2.
@   63  FILLER ??   ÅCHAR2.
@   65  L7TRMIS ??  IB4.
@   69  L7FBRID ??  IB4.
@   73  L7DANDAT ?? IB4.
@   77  L7DANTID ?? IB4.
@   81  L7FANDAT ?? IB4.
@   85  L7FSYST ??  ÅCHAR8.
@   93  L7ARKIV ??  IB8.
@   101 BHTYP ??    PD2.
@   103 BTILBAGE ?? PD1.
@   104 BAUTOMAT ?? PD1.
@   105 BGEBKAT ??  PD2.
@   107 BGEBSTED ?? PD2.
@   109 BPOSART ??  PD2.
@   111 BFOROMR ??  PD2.
@   113 BSFORM ??   PD2.
@   115 BSERVART ?? PD2.
@   117 BFRASTED ?? PD6.




;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you want to read the record based on certain value of LAENGDE, otherwise ignore that record entirely. Correct? If this is the case then you can use line hold specifier trailing @ to solve your problem. You can read more about it in the following SAS documentation on [SAS INPUT Statemet](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146292.htm). Also, below is a ref code for your help. Let me know if it helps.

```
data my_data;
infile datalines missover;
input @1 indicator $8. @;

if indicator='read' then do;
  input @9  first_name $9.
        @18 last_name  $9.
        ;
end;
else delete;
datalines4;
read    john     doe
ignore  whatever something
read    abc      xyz
ignore  whatever something
ignore  whatever something
read    abc1     xyz1
;;;;
run;
proc print;run;
```

Comment: I got an idea with your if statement.
then you write ELSE in your statement. Is it possible to get a "do nothing command" or bring the same value?

Comment: you can replace "else delete;" with "else input;" to get ignore records without first_name and last_name..i think that's what you are looking for here

Comment: hmm no only want the specified data. In your example i only want read.
But maybe your example is great, but i dont really know how to use the datalines4.